# 200k data (1.3 GB) in mongo collection and query return error in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I am new in NodeJS and Mongo DB. I have a collection with 0.2 Million data (1.3 GB) in mongo Collection.

I am using the local server and using the window machine.

I am using the NodeJS and ReactJS to execute the query with this collection. I have search keyword in only 2 columns and got the below error:

Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[33332:000001D061D9E0A0]    42563 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2039.7 (2060.1) -> 2039.5 (2061.1) MB, 304.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.065, current mu = 0.013) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[33332:000001D061D9E0A0]    42881 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 2040.5 (2058.1) -> 2040.4 (2059.8) MB, 313.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.040, current mu = 0.015) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF6CFDC481F napi_wrap+110783
 2: 00007FF6CFD67F26 v8::base::CPU::has_sse+61862
 3: 00007FF6CFD68E26 node::OnFatalError+294
 4: 00007FF6D06423BE v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+94
 5: 00007FF6D062718D v8::SharedArrayBuffer::Externalize+781
 6: 00007FF6D04D02CC v8::internal::Heap::EphemeronKeyWriteBarrierFromCode+1516
 7: 00007FF6D04DB6EA v8::internal::Heap::ProtectUnprotectedMemoryChunks+1258
 8: 00007FF6D04D8829 v8::internal::Heap::PageFlagsAreConsistent+2457
 9: 00007FF6D04CD3D1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+2049
10: 00007FF6D04CB5D5 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateExternalBackingStore+1349
11: 00007FF6D04E5455 v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::ShouldDoContextDisposalMarkCompact+1029
12: 00007FF6D04E58A5 v8::internal::Factory::AllocateRaw+37
13: 00007FF6D04F93E6 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithFiller+86
14: 00007FF6D04F96F3 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArrayWithMap+35
15: 00007FF6D0306AE0 v8::internal::HashTable<v8::internal::NameDictionary,v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::EnsureCapacity<v8::internal::Isolate>+208
16: 00007FF6D0304156 v8::internal::Dictionary<v8::internal::NameDictionary,v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add<v8::internal::Isolate>+102
17: 00007FF6D030D416 v8::internal::BaseNameDictionary<v8::internal::NameDictionary,v8::internal::NameDictionaryShape>::Add+118
18: 00007FF6D020178C v8::internal::Runtime::GetObjectProperty+2204
19: 00007FF6D06CB27D v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+465325
20: 000001E7C8B837B6
```

Comment: Increase the memory on your machine\virtual machine\server.

Comment: I am using the local machine. My Machine is Window. So what is the next part?

Comment: Can you show the related codes?

Comment: Increase the memory allocated to Node.

Comment: I got the one solution.... node --max-old-space-size=8192 index.js  but this is not working

Comment: Assuming your `lack` meant actually `lac` (or `lakh`), the Indian word for 100 000 -- please don't use those here, there's people here who don't live in India.

Comment: I really don't believe we have 650 million users from India here. But of course, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The v8 option "--max-old-space-size" should help you.
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_max_old_space_size_size_in_megabytes